# I want to store the IDs of some tweets using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, slice, tweepy, indices

This code prints the IDs but also raises a TypeError

```
for tweet in client.search_recent_tweets(search_string):
    for tweet_id in tweet:
        print(tweet_id['id'])
```

Simply printing Tweet gives the following data

```
Response(data=[<Tweet id=#ID text='#text'>], includes={}, errors=[], meta={'newest_id': '#ID of first tweet', 'oldest_id': '#ID of last tweet', 'result_count': 10, 'next_token': '#Token no.'})
```

I basically want to extract the Tweet IDs

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how your double loop is supposed to work.

Anyway, you can see that the tweets are in the `response.data`, so simply iterate through it:

```py
response = client.search_recent_tweets(search_string)  # Get the API response

tweets = response.data                                 # Tweets are the data

for tweet in tweets:                                   # Iterate through the tweets
    print(tweet.id)                                    # You can now access their id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation on how to get tweet fields. - https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).